# NgIf does not work properly in template for angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the following test code for angular 2 where I output true or false depending on whether I have token in local storage or not. In this case, I do have it as I can see it under application in my chrome developer tool. However, even thought I am seeing

> isLoggedIn() returns true

multiple times when this component is rendered, I am also seeing the browser displaying ...false... on the page. Does anyone know why?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-authentication',
    template: `
        <div *ngIf="isLoggedIn()">
            ...true...
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="!isLoggedIn()">
            ...false...
        </div>
    `
})
export class AuthenticationComponent {
    isLoggedIn() {
        console.log('isLoggedIn() returns', localStorage.getItem('token') !== null)
        return (localStorage.getItem('token') !== null);
    }
}
```

Comment: You did set a break point at `return (localStorage.getItem('token') !== null)` and really verified that the return value is true, right?

Comment: Do you change 'token' anywhere in your code?